# MS Access 2016: Set a field to populate when another field was last updated

Tags: date, reporting, updates, ms-access-2016

I have a split asset database in MS Access 2016 and would like to set up a report to be emailed out each day to show what project codes have been changed.  The report will show specific fields from the table.

I have added a column to the Asset table which I want to have the date populated in when the Project code is changed on the front end form.  How do i set it to update?  I can only find ways to update based on a row not a specific field.